How to get all subscriptions of an product in woocomerace plugin development?
i want to get all subscriptions of any product in WP plugin development. if anyone have any idea how can I get all? it show me 10 I changed the post_per_page but nothing work
```<?PHP $product_id = 9258; 
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions( array(
    'product_id'       => $product_id,
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'paged'            => 1,
) );```


https://github.com/riclain/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/wcs-functions.php#L332: 'subscriptions_per_page' The number of subscriptions to return. Set to -1 for unlimited. Default 10.
